# HTTP Bad Request response to Java POST call

Tags: java, rest, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm attempting to query a REST api using POST requests in a java application. I think I've set everything correctly, but I keep getting a Bad Request response.

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(requestURI);
request.addHeader("accept", "application/json");
request.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(requestBody + new Integer(PatientId).toString() + "}");
request.setEntity(entity);
```

The requestBody, accompanied by the number and curly brace, are valid JSON, and the requestURI is copy and pasted straight out of the API documentation, so I know I shouldn't be getting a Bad Request due to those.

Am I missing something in the setup?

Comment: Can you do this with a Rest Client for a browser with everything being the same and see what that returns? Also you are adding a close curly brace at the end - I'm not sure but it looks like it's out of place as the open one is missing

Comment: @Sunil I tried it out in a REST Client, with just my "accept" and "content-type" headers set to "application/json", and it executed fine.

Comment: Can you set entity.setContentType("application/json") instead of adding it? When you print out **requestBody + new Integer(PatientId).toString() + "}"** do you get the request body that you expect? I feel that it's got to do with your request body (and the suspicious close"}") since everything else looks good

Answer (score 1):

The [`Content-Length`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.2) header is missing. Some servers don't report the correct 4xx error (411 Length Required) and just issue a generic Bad Request error.

Comment: I don't think so. I just executed the exact same call through a browser REST client, and it executed perfectly.

Comment: There needs to be either a `Content-Length`, `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, or `Connection: close` header in order to inform the server how big the entity is. I don't know what the browser REST client is sending, but your code does not appear to be sending any of these.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being a random slash that wasn't included in my URI.